# Image displaying through HTTP POST method not displaying after upgrading from PHP 7.2 to PHP 8

Tags: php, php-7.2, php-8

So I am passing a file upload data through a form POST to a PREVIEW pdf. It used to work, but we recently changed to PHP 8 and I haven't managed to adapt it.

Here is the code block that gets the the file upload data and converts it to a bit64 in order to display it.

```
$imageName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

   if (!empty($imageName)) {
        $str = file_get_contents($imageName);
        $b64img = base64_encode($str);

        $imagePath = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $b64img;
    }
```

The Way the image is being passed through is with a form POST method.

```
<input type="submit" id="previewbtn" name="previewbtn" class="center-block"
                        style="width:100%; background-color:white" value="Preview" 
                        formmethod="post"
                        formaction="/incidents/incidentResult.pdf.php?PREVIEW" />
```

[image]

If more information is needed, let me know.

This is the Error it's giving me.
[image]

Comment: `data://text/plain;` looks weird to me, even if it worked before. The `//` shouldn’t be there, I’d think, and I’d also assume your mime type should march the image’s

Comment: @ChrisHaas Before if the `//` was not there is would output the text like it is doing now.

Comment: Needs more details on the "passing to a PREVIEW pdf" part. That is presumably using some sort of 3rd-party library? Have you checked that for compatibility with PHP 8?

Comment: just to note `data:image/png;base64,` also didn't work before. Only `text/plain` worked

Comment: @CBroe I have made the Edits

Comment: But the mere submission of a form does not create a PDF on its own ... you need to show us the relevant coding in `/incidents/incidentResult.pdf.php`.

Comment: I am showing you the relevant code. With the form POST you literally post the element and to get the upload file you need to handle it like that element is on the same page. that is what the `$imageName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];` is for. With this I can then convert the whole file upload contents to a string and convert it to a base64.

Comment: I can show you how I create a FormData() in ajax in order to pass it through to a different php page so I can save it, and how handling it on the pdf side differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have changed code and never adapted this section. The if exists is out of syntax. I just commented it out and it seems to be working now. Thanks to all who helped me.

```
    // if (file_exists($imagePath)) {

        if ($reasonCode === "Overload") {
            $pdf->Image($imagePath, 15, 30, 180, 250, $imageType);
        } else {
            $pdf->Image($imagePath, 15, 85, 180, 195, $imageType);
        }
    // } else {
    //     $pdf->Cell($leftMargArr["TRAN"], $heightArr["TRAN"], "Image could not be loaded, at path:", $borderArr["ALL"], 1, 'L');
    //     $pdf->Cell($leftMargArr["TRAN"], $heightArr["TRAN"], $imagePath, $borderArr["ALL"], 1, 'L');
    // }
```

[image]

Comment: So the part of the code actually causing the problem was not in your question, in future please read [how to create a minimal, reproduce example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow people to understand the actual issue.

Comment: I understand. When I posted the question, it never occurred to me tat this could have been the problem.